# QR code not appear in email when i sent email. Although I am converted it to img

Tags: laravel, email, qr-code

I try to send email with qrcode, i convert it to image and it work on localhost, but when i send it to email the qr code does not appear!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body dir="rtl">
<p>{!! $data['message'] !!}</p>   
<img src="data:image/png;base64, {!! base64_encode(QrCode::format('png')->size(100)->generate('helloworld')) !!} ">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by type:

```
<img src="{!!$message->embedData(QrCode::format('png')->size(200)->encoding('UTF-8')->generate($data['qr']), 'QrCode.png', 'image/png')!!}">
```